# Downloading entire contents of Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Is there a way I can download the entire Active Directory. I know I could write script to crawl each and every user's entry that are linked in the hierarchy. But that would be very inefficient. I wanted to know if there is already a neat solution for this.

Thanks.

(I would prefer a solution that could be scripted for scheduled downloads)

Comment: The reason is that I need to download AD. I know that it can be large. But I want to build an app that create visual stats around user's hierarchical data. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than enumerating all AD objects starting at the top (using a Directory searcher component of some sort), I'm not really sure how to do this programmatically...

One solution - not programming, but using an existing tool - might be [Sysinternals AD Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907) which allows you to connect to an Active Directory and store a snapshot of it on disk.

[image]

I don't know what format that snapshot is in, unfortunately - maybe you could get in touch with Mark Russinovich and ask if that format is documented / available in some form (or check it out yourself to see if you can figure it out).

Other options might be:

- [Directory Services Data Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa813600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (DSDE)
- [LDAP Data Interchange Format (LDIF)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237677)
- [CSVDE - CSV Data Export (from LDAP)](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/networking/simplify-admin-tasks-by-exporting-active-directory-data-with-csvde/427)

Comment: Great! Looks like this might be what I need. Thanks.